# I need help creating a web scraping bot using python that pulls specific information

Tags: python, web-scraping

web scraping bot that gathers marking information to help with creating a business plan for any niche. The types of data I would like to scrape would be (specific) market caps, emails, phone numbers, and more.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you need to look at Python projects like Scrapy or BeatifulSoup.